# Using web assembly on iOS

Tags: app-store, blazor-webassembly, webassembly, rust-wasm

Hi I would like to ask if the webassembly technology is supported by wkwebview or if there are particular limitations. The second question is once an app has been developed where I have some sections inside that make use of web assembly modules, is it possible to publish them on the appstore or are there limitations?
thanks for the replies.